# Using apps script to create charts. Range gets added to previous charts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

I have several sets of data that I want to generate graphs from to insert into a report.
The data is structured on one sheet with a unique ID in columna A, min, max, avr, median as headers in Column B and the corresponding values in the corresponding row for each "header".
The code I have successfully gathers the data, creates a new chart for that range and inserts it to the sheet with a unique title.

However...
Each time a new chart is created and a new range added to that chart, the same range is added to ALL previously created chart as well. So in the end, if I have 20 sets of data, I'll end up with 20 charts, where the chart that was generated first has the range of all 20 sets, while the last chart only has one set of data.

I have asked both chatGPT and google Bard but they have been unable to assist on this issue...
This is my code for generating the charts.

```
function newChart(range, sheet, metadata, minvalue) {
  var maintitle = metadata.title;
  var yaxis = metadata.yaxis;
  var xaxis = metadata.xaxis;
  var dimensions = [700, 300];
  var range = sheet.getRange(range);
  var anchor = range.getRow();

  var options = {
    width: dimensions[0],
    height: dimensions[1],
    title: maintitle,
    titleTextStyle: { color: '#D52B1E', fontName: 'Anton', fontSize: 24, bold: true },
    backgroundColor: '#37424A',
    fontName: 'Helvetica Neue',
    vAxis: { title: yaxis, minValue: minvalue },
    hAxis: { title: xaxis }
  }

  // Create a new chart object for each chart
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .setPosition(anchor, 6, 0, 0)
    .setOption('width', options.width)
    .setOption('height', options.height)
    .setOption('title', options.title)
    .setOption('titleTextStyle', options.titleTextStyle)
    .setOption('backgroundColor', options.backgroundColor)
    .setOption('fontName', options.fontName)
    .setOption('vAxis', options.vAxis)
    .setOption('hAxis', options.hAxis)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true);

  // Add the range to the current chart
  chart = chart.addRange(range);

  // Insert the chart into the sheet
  sheet.insertChart(chart.build());
}
```

In this version the element passed to the function as "range" is just a string in A1-notation.
My first version passed the range object but that didnt work either.

Any explanation for this behavior and how to work around it?
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest you `console.log(range)`  for each call to function `newChart`

Comment: I do, The range is always the intended range. Which is also reflected in the new chart. 
The issue is that the same range is also added to the previous charts as well.

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that i define the range by using getLastRow() and that that would update the ranges of the previous charts aswell somehow but my knowledge with the inner workings of Javascript is not enough to fully comprehend what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a new chart and adds the specified range to it. However, the described behavior where the range is added to all previously created charts is unusual and doesn't appear to be an issue with your code. It's possible that there's an issue elsewhere in your script or with the Apps Script environment itself.

A better approach

To address the problem, consider creating a completely new sheet, generate the chart on that new sheet, and then copy the chart back to the original sheet. This will ensure each chart is isolated during its creation.

```js
function newChart(range, sheet, metadata, minvalue) {
  var maintitle = metadata.title;
  var yaxis = metadata.yaxis;
  var xaxis = metadata.xaxis;
  var dimensions = [700, 300];
  var range = sheet.getRange(range);
  var anchor = range.getRow();
  
  var tempSheetName = "TempSheetForChart" + Date.now(); // unique sheet name
  var tempSheet = sheet.getSpreadsheet().insertSheet(tempSheetName);

  var options = {
    width: dimensions[0],
    height: dimensions[1],
    title: maintitle,
    titleTextStyle: { color: '#D52B1E', fontName: 'Anton', fontSize: 24, bold: true },
    backgroundColor: '#37424A',
    fontName: 'Helvetica Neue',
    vAxis: { title: yaxis, minValue: minvalue },
    hAxis: { title: xaxis }
  };

  var chart = tempSheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .setPosition(1, 6, 0, 0)  // adjusted to top-left of the temp sheet
    .setOption('width', options.width)
    .setOption('height', options.height)
    .setOption('title', options.title)
    .setOption('titleTextStyle', options.titleTextStyle)
    .setOption('backgroundColor', options.backgroundColor)
    .setOption('fontName', options.fontName)
    .setOption('vAxis', options.vAxis)
    .setOption('hAxis', options.hAxis)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .addRange(range)
    .build();

  tempSheet.insertChart(chart);
  var charts = tempSheet.getCharts();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    sheet.insertChart(charts[i]);
  }

  // Remove the temporary sheet after copying the chart
  sheet.getSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(tempSheet);
}
```

With this approach, each chart is generated on a fresh temporary sheet, then copied back to the desired sheet, minimizing the potential of previously generated charts to interfere.

Comment: Tried this but it didnt work. Same issue as previously.